# Subscription to tags doesn't work well with certain characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, subscription, search-subscription

I have subscribed via email to receive StackOverflow Careers items via keyword search.

One of my keywords is "C#". But I'm receiving ads that don't contain "C#" at all (I guess somehow the "#" is being stripped from the search).

Can you fix this bug?

Comment: This **is** the correct place to report bugs...

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah, I saw the "bug" tag later when I was going to submit.

Comment: I am not having this problem with my own subscription to “C#”, though I see that you are subscribed to a combination of terms. I will subscribe to the same thing and see if I can reproduce it…

Comment: Matt, any news?

Comment: @MattSherman , today I just got a new alert and it seems the problem has been finally fixed!

Comment: and this is broken again (I guess someone changed it to be an AND, and now it's back to be an OR)